# Overriding in multiple inheritance

Tags: solidity, inheritance, function-override

If I have the following contracts:

```js
contract A {
   function _delegate() internal virtual {
      //some code
   }
}
```

```js
contract B is A {
   //some code not including _delegate()
}
```

```js
contract C is B {
   function _delegate() internal override {
      //some code
   }
}
```

..and if I deploy `Contract C` and call `_delegate()`, which code will run? The one from Contract A or from Contract C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Contract A:** You have the initial `_delegate() function`.

In **Contract B:** `_delegate() function` is inherited, from **Contract A**.

In **Contract C:** `_delegate() function` is inherited, from **Contract B**, which inherited that function from **Contract A**.

However, in **Contract C** you are overriding `_delegate() function`, so that code will be the valid one.

Answering your question: If you deploy Contract C and call _delegate(), you will get //some code from Contract C.